# Python in Sublime Text 3 won't respond on simple operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, runtime-error, interpreter

My editor Sublime Text 3 don't respond on code like: `2+2`

Here is the case
[image]

Every other code like: `print("Hello World")` , works perfectly. Is there any solution or I need to change editor?

Comment: Try `print(str(2 + 2))`

Comment: it responded but didn't display on console

Comment: It works, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my editor Sublime Text 3 don't respond on code
>   like: 2+2

If you want this behaviour you need to fire up a python interpreter. Sublime Text 3 does not interpret your code. It just executes your scripts.

If you want to display output, you'll need to `print` it.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful as beginner in coding.

Comment: @thecaptainjera No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

I just didn't display on console. You can use `print(2+2)` to print out the result

Comment: Yea this works fine but in python shell 3.6 only : 2+2 result is 4. Thanks!

Comment: @thecaptainjera when you interactive with shell, it shows you the result but when you put your code in file, it only display the printing/logging lines in the terminal

Comment: Yea I got it, also i have problem with input : input("name:")+input("lastname:") it only shows name input and can't go on lastname?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour. When running a script file, you have to use `print` to display any outputs. For example:

```
x = 2 + 2
print(x)
```

Comment: Mhm, I am beginner so I didn't know that. In python shell 3.6 only 2+2 gives result, without print or using variables. Thank you!